# Can't git submodule in my local repo

Tags: git

My colleague at the company has created a submodule that sits inside the origin, and I was asked to `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` to get the submodule synced locally, but I failed to do so - whenever I run `git submodule update` it says

```
Cloning into 'blablabla'...
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:<organisation>/testing-tools' into submodule path '<root>/testing/testing-tools' failed
Failed to clone 'testing/testing-tools'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '<root>testing/testing-tools'...
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

However, when I `git clone git@github.com:<organisation>/testing-tools.git` outside the root it's fine, meaning that SSH key is working and I have access to that respository of the submodule.

The current version of Git is 2.11.0.windows.3.

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Taihai

Comment: did you run both commands in the same terminal? you can try loading your key in pageant. It is strange that the terminal also does not recognize github.com as a trusted host.

Comment: Similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43788715/1615903

Comment: @DennisvanSchaik I ran them in the same terminal. I have a separate host account, which is github.com-<organisation>, but its HostName is github.com. I use it as the host of the repository. For the sake of posting I modified the terminal's response but didn't realise it might show that github.com isn't recognised as a trusted host? In any case, I am still not able to update the submodule...

Comment: @1615903 I changed the ownership but am still not able to update the submodule.. :(