# Git submodule using a different ssh key?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to add a private repository as a git submodule.

I can clone the repository like so `git clone <repo_url>` but when I use `git submodule add <repo_url> <folder_destination>` I get back:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Comment: Try add a separate entry in your .ssh/config for the private repo host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the ownership on my `.git/modules` folder had changed to root.

I was able to fix the issue by running:

```
chown -R philip:philip .git/modules/
```